# Barrier error during initiating HRMP channel with Rockmine on Rococo

Tags: polkadot, parachain, xcm, rococo, hrmp

I want to open HRMP channel with Rockmine on rococo. But I got the Barrier error and can't understand what is wrong with my request.

[image: Here is the error that I found on rococo side.]

This is my encoded call data
0x29000101000210000400000000070010a5d4e81300000000070010a5d4e800060003005ed0b2381700e8030000e8030000009001000d010004000100a10f

There is no additional events that can help me to figure out what exactly wrong.
Does anybody has any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, this is because you're using a non-root account to send the XCM of HRMP request. **You should use sudo or governance to do this.**
If you use a non-root account to call `polkadotXcm.send`, [it will add the `DescendOrigin` instruction as the first instruction](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.26/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs#L1068) into your messsage, and then [blocked by rococo `AllowTopLevelPaidExecutionFrom` barrier](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.26/xcm/xcm-builder/src/barriers.rs#L69).

Make sure your sovereign account in the relaychain has sufficient balance to withdraw, otherwise it will `FailedToTransactAsset`

Then, there are several improvements you need to pay attention to, although they're not releated to `barrier`:

1. You can add a `RefundSurplus` instruction between `Transact` and `DepositAsset`, it can refund your surplus weight for transact.
2. The `beneficiary` of `DepositAsset` should be your sovereign account on rococo, your paraId is 2124, so it should be `{0, X1(Parachain(2124))}`, rather than `Parachain(1000)`. It will put unspent tokens into your sovereign account on rococo.

[image]

Comment: Useful encoded call data from Guantong
0x29000101000214000400000000070010a5d4e81300000000070010a5d4e80006000700f2052a01381700e8030000e803000000900100140d0100040001003121

Comment: Yeah, I delete it because it only can be decoded in your parachain. And I added the screeshot for everyone to see.

Comment: When exactly the transaction will be executed after motion?
https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fpencol-roc-00.pendulumchain.tech#/council/motions

Comment: Sorry. I have the same Barrier error. Can we talk via some google meeting?

Comment: Could you please provide your execution block number or TG: https://t.me/jiguantong

Comment: I think that question is off topic. Maybe you should ask another question about how motion works. I’d like to answer it there.

Comment: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4971/i-created-a-motion-and-want-to-know-when-code-will-be-executed

Answer (score 1):

Great tutorial for opening channel with Common good parachain.

[link](https://hackmd.io/ECywP_7_SLeTvWCTfQPkqw?view)