# I created a motion and want to know when code will be executed?

Tags: polkadot, parachain, motion

I created a motion and want to know when code will be executed?
When all voters voted for motion and someone execute "close" transaction.
Will it be executed immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two conditions.

Once the motion gets closed:

1. If the motion gets enough votes, it will be executed immediately.
2. If the motion doesn't get enough votes, it will be dropped.