# XCM error. OverweightEnqueued event instead of opening HRMP channel

Tags: parachain, xcm, error, hrmp

[image: upward message event]

What is the reason of OverweightEnqueued event?

There is the place of code where event OverweightEnqueued produced...

[image]

Comment: Could you share your call and parameters?

Comment: Amplitude runtime:
https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fpencol-roc-00.pendulumchain.tech#/extrinsics/decode
hex-encoded call
0x0c00290001010002140004000000000b00a0724e180913000000000b00a0724e18090006000b007083d05d06381700e8030000e803000000900100140d0100040001003121

Comment: Try reduce this `requireWeightAtMost: 7,000,000,000,000`.

Comment: what does parameter means?
is there some example for this parameter for opening hrmp?

Comment: Try reduce to 500_000_000_000 or 5_000_000_000 (. I think it is safety measure in current XCM configs to allow  bad configuration taking too much money.

Comment: It sets up a maximum weight for that transact to ensure you won't waste too many unexpected fees.

Comment: So it fixed to use correct xcm call with sudo:

0x0c0029000101000214000400000000070010a5d4e81300000000070010a5d4e80006000700f2052a01381700e8030000e803000000900100140d0100040001003121
from our parachain to rococo
or from our parachain to Bifrost
0x0c0029000101000214000400000000070010a5d4e81300000000070010a5d4e80006000700f2052a01381700d1070000e803000000900100140d0100040001003121

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is because **`requireWeightAtMost` you specified is greater than `umpMaxIndividualWeight`**, you should use the values from [my answer in your other question(5,000,000,000),](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/4925/1959) `hrmp.hrmpInitOpenChannel` does not need so much weight. And I'll explain to you why.

First, you need to know that resources available to chains are limited, and weights are the mechanism used to manage the time it takes to validate a block.**The amount of weight a block may contain is limited**. Therefore, relaychain limits the max used weight of individual ump's transact, to ensure that other transactions can be successfully executed. You can find the limit in configuration. Obviously, your `7,000,000,000,000` is greater than `20,000,000,000`, then put into the overweight queue and may be dispatched later by [`service_overweight`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.26/runtime/parachains/src/ump.rs#L349)(still may error due to `WeightOverLimit`). [image]
[image]
Then,

> what does parameter means?

It means the most weight you are willing to pay for the transact call(here is `hrmp.hrmpInitOpenChannel`).If the weight required by this transact call(about `786524000`) exceeds the `requireWeightAtMost` you specified, it will fail with `MaxWeightInvalid`. If not and lower than `umpMaxIndividualWeight`, it'll be executed(make sure other values are correct) and the surplus weight will be refunded by the `RefundSurplus` instruction.

Comment: Hi. I use all parameters that you advise. But now I have other error.
https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frococo-rpc.polkadot.io#/explorer/query/0x07a63bd3d790daa46ee9f03a7119fa7903882f1105f4fd5abf30f1594ef12fa8
{
  Incomplete: [
    1,000,000,000
    FailedToTransactAsset
  ]
}

Comment: Make sure your sovereign account in the relaychain has sufficient balance to withdraw. Your sovereign account is `5Ec4AhP2VP3kQcM928TnKuw9miE7yCDvRxd3mqVNA28pE3m4`, transfer some ROC to it on rococo.

Comment: How it is possible to check? 
https://rococo.subscan.io/parachain/2124
Is it right way to check it?
Seems that it is enough  ROC tokens on relay chain.
I am trying to open HRMP with Rockmine.

Comment: https://rococo.subscan.io/account/5Ec4AhP2VP3kQcM928TnKuw9miE7yCDvRxd3mqVNA28pE3m4

Comment: Please. Tell me how you find the sovereign account for our parachain?

Comment: Refer to this question: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/how-to-calculate-sovereignaccount-for-parachain/1210#1210

Comment: Awesome! You are really substrate ninja!!! Thank you!