# XCM between multiple parachains

Tags: parachain, xcm, xcmp

I am gonna transfer the customized message which is actually the string in JSON format for representing some information from one parachain to another one.
But I can't find the right functions or specific steps, while there are some XCM demos for transfer the tokens between multiple parachains.
If anyone have some idea, please contact here to give me your hand, thanks.

---

I tested XCM between parachain 2000 and parachain 2001.
At the moment I could see the "Barrier error" just like the image below.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

All parameters of XCM were almost same as here, [How to open HRMP channels between parachains?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5445/how-to-open-hrmp-channels-between-parachains).

But I couldn't create a new HRMP channel via this XCM.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, when you send a cross-chain message, you actually want to either transfer the token or call the method on target chain.

As you said **customized message**, what do you want the message to do after it reaches the target chain? Call a function with it as an argument? If so, you could use the `transact` instruction in XCM.

For example: Send XCM to Polkadot and call `remark` on Polkadot with customized message "hello world" as parameter.

1. Get the encoded call data `0x00012c68656c6c6f20776f726c64`
   [image]
2. Send XCM to Polkadot via `polkadotXcm.send`

```
WithdrawAsset(...)
BuyExecution(...)
Transact(0x00012c68656c6c6f20776f726c64) 
RefundSurplus
DepositAsset(...)
```

---

*Updates to follow up on question*:

You should use **sudo or Governance** to send the XCM to open HRMP.

Refer to: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/4925/1959

Comment: Thanks for your help, Guantong.

Comment: I will try and leave my feedback here, if you are available at the moment, please check my message.

Comment: @TinyDev Please update your question to add your XCM you sent so that I can find what's wrong.

Comment: @TinyDev Could you edit your question and add the XCM instructions or screenshot?Comment is not convenient.

Comment: @TinyDev I have updated my answer. But I think it's not related to the original question, If you are still confused, you can open a new question, I am willing to help you

Comment: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5654/i-cant-open-a-hrmp-channel-between-the-parachains
Please check this question, @Guantong.